# Beginner JQuery Toggling classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on for a project. I have had a quick go at [coding some buttons(https://codepen.io/ryantinsley/pen/XqOBGb). I have created 2 states. A blue selected class and an outlined deselected class. I want to switch between these two classes each time I click on one of the buttons.

I have tried numerous things in jQuery and some things have worked to a point such as changing `h1` text colours, but apart from that nothing seems to work for me.

In short I am looking for the best way to toggle between the two buttons on every click.

Thanks in advance for all you help

```css
h1 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: light;
  display: inline;
}

#star {
  background-image: url("https://image.ibb.co/mdSJgT/Hollow_Star.png");
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#container {
  padding: 8px 8px;
  border: solid 1px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#starselect {
  background-image: url("https://image.ibb.co/hZ2Uo8/Filled_Star.png");
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#containerselect {
  padding: 8px 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #006DEF;
}

#h1select {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: light;
  display: inline;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="star"></div>
  <h1>Link</h1>
</div>

<div id="containerselect">
  <div id="starselect"></div>
  <h1 id="h1select">Link</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass

Answer (score 3, accepted):

convert your id into class and use [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) of jQuery. Here is an example.

```js
$("#button").on("click", function() {
  $(this).children().toggleClass("container containerselect");
  $(this).children().children().eq(0).toggleClass("star starselect");
  $(this).find("h1").toggleClass(" h1select");
});
```

```css
h1 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: light;
  display: inline;
}

.star {
  background-image: url("https://image.ibb.co/mdSJgT/Hollow_Star.png");
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container {
  padding: 8px 8px;
  border: solid 1px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.starselect {
  background-image: url("https://image.ibb.co/hZ2Uo8/Filled_Star.png");
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.containerselect {
  padding: 8px 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #006DEF;
}

.h1select {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: light;
  display: inline;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="star"></div>
    <h1>Link</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly create css using classes.

Then you can use :

```
$("#starselect").click(function() {
   $(this).removeClass('class2');
   $(this).addClass('class1');
});
```

PS: 
1. You can remove or add IDs using `attr()` function in Jquery. But that is not suggeseted. Because ID defines an element, not its styling.

2. You can also use `toggleClass()`

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following solution:

```
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jxdQav
```

jQuery

```
$('.divlink').on('click', function(e){
  $('.divlink').not(this).removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

HTML

```
 <div id="container" class="divlink">
     <div id ="star"></div>
    <h1>Link</h1>
 </div>

<div id="container" class="divlink active">
   <div id ="starselect"></div>
   <h1 id ="h1select">Link</h1>
</div>
```

CSS

```
h1 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: light;
  display: inline;
}

#star {
  background-image: url("https://image.ibb.co/mdSJgT/Hollow_Star.png");
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#container {
  padding: 8px 8px;
  border: solid 1px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#starselect {
  background-image: url("https://image.ibb.co/hZ2Uo8/Filled_Star.png");
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.active {
  padding: 8px 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #006DEF;
}

#h1select {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: light;
  display: inline;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: This is correct but switching if ````ID```` is not a correct approach.

Comment: @AkshayPrakash: To apply css on id is also not correct approach. Better is he take 'active' class and switch but this is solution as per his code.

Comment: Yes, as I have mentioned in my answer, ID defines the element, not the styling.